# Change Time format in long

Tags: java, android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I got time from Time-Picker like 13:50:00, now i want to convert this time into long format.How to convert this? Thanks in advance

```
Time t = Time.valueOf("13:50:00");
long longFormatTime = t.getTime();
System.out.println("longFormatTime="+longFormatTime);
```

this is giving "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" error

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Time.getTime()`-Method relating to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html).
You can use

```
Time t = Time.valueOf("13:50:00");
long longFormatTime = t.toMillis();
System.out.println("longFormatTime="+longFormatTime);
```

Read Documentation for more Informations: [Time.toMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#toMillis(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could try with Calendar instead Time.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds);
long startTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

or if you want current date in millis:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```